# Django: test failing on a view with @login_required

Tags: django, session, tdd, authentication

I'm trying to build a test for a view that's decorated with
@login_required, since I failed to make it work, I did a simple test
and still can't make it pass.

Here is the code for the simple test and the view:

```
def test_login(self):
    user = self._create_new_user()
    self.assertTrue(user.is_active)
    login = self.client.login(username=user.username,
password=self.data['password1'])
    self.failUnless(login, 'Could not log in')
    response = self.client.get('/accounts/testlogin/')
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)

@login_required
def testlogin(request):
    print 'testlogin !! '
    return HttpResponse('OK')
```

_create_new_user() is saving the user and there is a test inside that
method to see that is working.

The test fails in the response.status_code, returning 302 and the
response instance is of a HttpResponseRedirect, is redirecting it as
if not logged in.

Any clue? I'm missing something?

Regards
Esteban

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the answer:

> Python 2.6.5  made a change to the way
>   cookies are stored which is subtly
>   incompatible with the test client.
>   This problem has been fixed in the
>   1.1.X and trunk branches, but the fix hasn't yet made it into a formal
>   release.
>
> If you are using 1.1.X and Python
>   2.6.5, you're going to have problems with any test activity involving
>   cookies. You either need to downgrade
>   Python, or use the 1.1.X branch rather
>   than the 1.1.1 release.
>
> A 1.1.2 release (that will include the
>   fix for the problem you describe) will
>   be made at the same time that we
>   release 1.2 - hopefully, very very
>   soon.
>
> Yours, Russ Magee %-)

http://groups.google.com/group/django-users/browse_frm/thread/617457f5d62366ae/05f0c01fff0b9e6d?hl=en&lnk=gst&q=2.6.5#05f0c01fff0b9e6d

Answer (score 34):

This testcase works for me:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.test.client import Client
import unittest

class LoginTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.client = Client()
        self.user = User.objects.create_user('john', 'lennon@thebeatles.com', 'johnpassword')

    def testLogin(self):
        self.client.login(username='john', password='johnpassword')
        response = self.client.get(reverse('testlogin-view'))
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

I suggest you (if you don't use them already) to use the *reverse()* function and name your URLs. This way you are sure that you get always the right URL.

Comment: @aeby: I copied and pasted your code and still get a 302, are you using @login_required in your view?

Comment: Django version 1.1.1 - Double checked that the testlogin view is working from the browser and that is available only by logged in user

Comment: Yes I do:  

from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
@login_required
def testlogin(request):
    return HttpResponse("Test")

Answer (score 0):

OK I was to facing same problem @resto solved my problem.

creating user this way below, lets the test client get the user logged in and get the response other than redirect (302)

```
self.user = User.objects.create_user('john', 'lennon@thebeatles.com', 'johnpassword')
```

Answer (score -1):

I think your problem is with login. In your temporary/test db, the password is 'password1', but when you run your test the password you are giving is hashed and salted to '779ty6098yui8@#$%^TR^$67yt' which when compared won't be == to 'password1'.

solution:
change:
login = self.client.login(username=user.username,
password=self.data['password1'])

to:
login = self.client.force_login(username=user.username,
password=self.data['password1'])