# Django - Testing - Problems with @login_required decorator

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, testing, django-authentication

### Problem

**UPDATE**: This issue, it turns out, has little to do with the `@login_required` decorator!

I am getting finicky behavior when I try to test views that are decorated with `@login_required`.

I have one test that is actually able to go to a view decorated with `@login_required` (a password change view). A different test, however, always gets redirected to login. No matter which way I've tried to re-write it, it won't let my test user through, even though I am logging the user in and asserting that `user.is_authenticated()` beforehand.

Here's the relevant snippet of the test that's having issues:

```
# Log user in
self.client.login(username=user.username, password=user.password)
self.assertTrue(user.is_authenticated())

# Go to account_edit view
url = reverse('account_edit')
response = self.client.get(url)
self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
self.assertTemplateUsed(response, 'users/account_edit_form.html')
```

This inevitably redirects to the login view, as if the user were not logged in.

I can confirm that this behavior is not reflected in the "normal" functioning of the app; the decorator works exactly as expected when I actually run the server and then navigate to this view (i.e. it allows access when logged in, and redirects to login view).

Using Django 1.3.1. I am using the testrunner from django-nose, but I can confirm that this issue happens regardless of which testrunner I use.

Also, I found several previous questions, but the solutions suggested were either particular to older versions of Django, or not helpful in this case (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705235/django-test-failing-on-a-view-with-login-required) for example).

### Solution (combining two good answers)

I received two very good answers to this question, both of which highlighted important oversights in the snippet I posted. The issue had nothing to do with `@login_required`'s behavior, and everything to do with (a) signing the user in wrong and (b) checking the user authentication wrong.

I was having a hard time picking which answer to accept, but after a little thought, I've decided to accept Konrad Hałas's answer, since it pinpoints the crucial oversight on my part, that was the root of unexpected behavior.

Nonetheless, I would have figured this out much sooner if I had not been using the faulty test line `self.assertTrue(user.is_authenticated())`. So to emphasize that the solution was actually two parts, here are the two steps to fixing the problematic code:

```
# Log user in *NOTE: Password needs to be raw (from Konrad's answer)
self.client.login(username=user.username, password="pass")
self.assertTrue(user.is_authenticated()) # <-- still not correct
```

The assertion line is still faulty because a valid user always satisfies `user.is_authenticated()`. See Alasdair's info for an explanation of this gotcha. So step two of fixing this code is:

```
# Log user in *NOTE: Password needs to be raw (from Konrad's answer)
login_successful = self.client.login(username=user.username, password="pass")
self.assertTrue(login_successful) # Much better! (see Alasdair's answer)
```

Finally, should you need to test that your user was logged in *without* using `client.login` (i.e. testing a login form), this should work:

```
self.assertTrue(response.context['user'].is_authenticated())
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`user.password` is password hash. You can't log in with it. You need to use original password:

```
self.client.login(username=user.username, password='<user password>')
```

Comment: Oof. Too obvious! I knew that, too. (But I guess not well enough.) So I guess I can't use the approach I've been using -- to randomly grab a user from the (test) database and run the test using that user's credentials. I'll have to only use a user I know the password of in advance, or continue with this approach but add an extra step (i.e. use `user.set_password()` so I can change the password to a known one just for the sake of running the test).

Comment: Yes, you can't. Small OT: maybe try [factory_boy](https://github.com/dnerdy/factory_boy#customizing-creation) - it's better solution then django fixtures. Here you have example how to [deal with user password](https://gist.github.com/3504037)

Answer (score 3):

The gotcha here is that the [`is_authenticated`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_authenticated) method *always* returns `True` for a `User` instance.

In the template or view it can be useful - if `request.user.is_authenticated()` is `True`, then you have a real user, not an `AnonymousUser`, and can proceed accordingly. However, if you start off with a `User` object, as you have done, then `is_authenticated()` can be confusing!

You can check the return value of the test client's [`login()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_authenticated) method to test whether it was successful.

```
login_successful = c.login(username='fred', password='secret')
self.assertTrue(login_successful)
```

Comment: This is very useful too. This would have alerted me to the issue much earlier. Both your answer and Konrad's answer are right! I am currently integrating what I've learned from both of them and I will update my question accordingly, then accept an answer, soon.

Comment: This also works:         self.assertTrue(response.context['user'].is_authenticated()) -- i.e. it does NOT work if the login fails. This is useful if you test the login form itself.