# AssertionError: 302 != 200

Tags: python, django, testing

I tried to create a test in my tests.py

```
class TaskViewTests(TestCase):
    def test_task_view_with_no_task(self):
        """
        If no task exist, an appropriate message should be displayed.
        """
        userName = 'esutek'
        response = self.client.get(reverse('actuser:task',args=(userName,)))
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertContains(response, "No task are available.")
        self.assertQuerysetEqual(response.context['taskList'], [])
```

However it gives me this error message.
I don't have any clue why this happened. I just followed the tutorial.

actuser:task
views.py

```
def task(request, userName):
    """ User task list in actInbox
    """

    user = ActuserViewModel()
    user.get_task_list(userName)

    return render(request, 'actuser/task.html', {
                'userName': userName,
                'taskList': user.taskList,
                'dateToday': user.dateToday,
           })
```

viewmodels.py

```
def get_task_list(self, userName):
    self.taskList = Task.objects.filter(executor = userName, parent_task_id=EMPTY_UUID).order_by('due_date')
    #get date now with this format 05/11
    self.dateToday = datetime.date.today()
```

Actually I got 2 urls...

this is from the project

```
url(r'^(?P<userName>[0-9a-zA-Z--]+)/', include('actuser.urls', namespace="actuser")),
```

and this one is from actuser.urls

```
url(r'^task/$', views.task, name='task'),
```

Comment: Can you post the code for your 'actuser:task' view?

Comment: Okay... I will update my question

Comment: Also your `urls.py` please?

Comment: Yes, I just did... thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please check my updated question?

Comment: 1. Run `manage.py runserver` 2. Visit that view in browser 3. What lines do you see in `runserver` console?

Comment: this one?  File "/actinbox/task/tests.py", line 86, in test_task_view_with_no_task

Comment: self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)

Comment: The code snippets you posted seem correct. Probably some other urls and views are interfering in a weird way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[HTTP 302](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302) means that you are redirected to some other URL. You can do a redirect intentionally if you use a [RedirectView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/class-based-views/base/#redirectview) for example, or accidentally if you forget to write slash at the end of the request URL and you have [APPEND_SLASH](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#append-slash) enabled (in that case, you get HTTP 301 instead of 302).

You need a slash at the end:

```
url(r'^(?P<userName>[0-9a-zA-Z-]+)/task/$', ...
```

Comment: I have updated my question... Can you check it out.. I guess it is  because I got 2 urls

Comment: Sorry, my idea about slash doesn't apply to your case - you get 302, not 301.

Answer (score 4):

You could be getting a redirect if your view requires login.

You need to login first, this is a good example of how to do it:
[Django: test failing on a view with @login_required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705235/django-test-failing-on-a-view-with-login-required)

Briefly:

```
class LoginTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.client = Client()
        self.user = User.objects.create_user('john', 'lennon@thebeatles.com', 'johnpassword')

    def testLogin(self):
        self.client.login(username='john', password='johnpassword')
        response = self.client.get(reverse('testlogin-view'))
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

Comment: Tank you! I had the same problem and this line saved my day: self.client.login(username='john', password='johnpassword')