# Flask test gives response 302 when expecting 200

Tags: python, django, testing

I tried to create a test in my tests.py for the first time and I keep receiving errors such as:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/actinbox/task/tests.py", line 86, in test_task_view_with_no_task
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
AssertionError: 302 != 200
```

this is my tests.py

```
class TaskViewTests(TestCase):
    def test_task_view_with_no_task(self):
        """
        If no task exist, an appropriate message should be displayed.
        """
        userName = 'esutek'
        response = self.client.get(reverse('actuser:task',args=(userName,)))
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertContains(response, "No task are available.")
        self.assertQuerysetEqual(response.context['taskList'], [])
```

However it gives me this error message.
I don't have any clue why this happened. I just followed the tutorial.

Actually I got 2 urls...

this is from the project

```
url(r'^(?P<userName>[0-9a-zA-Z--]+)/', include('actuser.urls', namespace="actuser")),
```

and this one is from actuser.urls

```
url(r'^task/$', views.task, name='task'),
```

Comment: Didn't you ask exactly the same question a few hours ago here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33274874/assertionerror-302-200 ?

Comment: @FredGarcia can you show us what your `views.task` is?